# Multiple AND conditions on the same column [Servicestack.OrmLite]

Tags: c#, sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

I was wondering if it's possible to have multiple `AND` conditions on the same column using `Servicestack.OrmLite`. This is the `SELECT` statement I printed out, but It always returns 0. I should get the product count from the products having both specifications with id 1016 and 17.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "Product"."Id") 
FROM "Product" 
INNER JOIN "ProductManufacturer" 
ON ("Product"."Id" = "ProductManufacturer"."ProductId") 
INNER JOIN "ProductSpecificationAttribute" 
ON ("Product"."Id" = "ProductSpecificationAttribute"."ProductId")
WHERE ("ProductManufacturer"."ManufacturerId" = 6) 
AND ("ProductSpecificationAttribute"."SpecificationAttributeOptionId" = 1016) 
AND ("ProductSpecificationAttribute"."SpecificationAttributeOptionId" = 17)
```

Comment: "Why" "does" "it" "spew" "all" "those" "awful" "double" "quotes"? Is it to help readability? Because "LOL" "it" "does" "not."

Comment: @AaronBertrand this is the SELECT statement I get using Servicestack.OrmLite 
=> query.ToSelectStatement();

Comment: If OrmLite can't figure out what an `OR` is and can't produce statements without all those terrible double quotes, I think you're using the wrong ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single column value can't possibly have two values at the same time.

What you want is either:

```sql
AND
(
  ProductSpecificationAttribute.SpecificationAttributeOptionId = 1016
  OR  
  ProductSpecificationAttribute.SpecificationAttributeOptionId = 17
)
```

Or, more succinctly:

```sql
AND
(
  ProductSpecificationAttribute.SpecificationAttributeOptionId 
  IN (1016, 17)
)
```

And turn off whatever option is forcing your tool to "inject" "double" "quotes" "around" "every" "entity" "name" because it makes the query text unmanageable. You might also consider using aliases and schema prefixes, like `INNER JOIN dbo.ProductSpecificationAttribute AS psa`...

After further clarification... the goal is to find products where they have both of those attributes *on different rows*, which isn't clear from the description or the code ORMLite barfed out. Here's what you want in that case (there are several ways to do this, but converting everything to `EXISTS` also allows you to remove the `DISTINCT` from the `COUNT`, which is never free):

```
SELECT COUNT(Product.Id) FROM dbo.Product AS p
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ProductManufacturer AS pm 
    WHERE pm.ProductId = p.Id AND pm.ManufacturerId = 6
)
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ProductSpecificationAttribute AS psa
    WHERE psa.ProductId = p.Id
    AND psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId = 1016
)
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ProductSpecificationAttribute AS psa
    WHERE psa.ProductId = p.Id
    AND psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId = 17
);
```

If `ProductSpecificationAttribute` is poorly index and this leads to two scans, you could change that by saying something like this (untested, but I'm happy to test it out if you can [produce a db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle):

```
SELECT COUNT(Product.Id) FROM dbo.Product AS p
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ProductManufacturer AS pm 
    WHERE pm.ProductId = p.Id 
    AND pm.ManufacturerId = 6
)
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ProductSpecificationAttribute AS psa
    WHERE psa.ProductId = p.Id
    AND psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId IN (17, 1016)
    GROUP BY psa.ProductId, psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId) > 1
);
```

It's also really weird that the table `ProductManufacturer` has a list of `ProductID`s in it that point back to `Product` - usually `Product` would have a `ManufacturerID` that points in the other direction.

Anyway, you might consider using stored procedures that your ORM can call if it has problems creating queries beyond basic CRUD (which is unfortunately a limitation of all ORMs to some degree - they're great at the basics, covering 80% of the use case, but they're terrible at the other 20% - unfortunately most of us end up needing that other 20% before too long).

Comment: In my example a product can have multiple specifications. But need to get only the products have those exact 2 specifications.

For example: The products where (color = black) and (gender = men)

Comment: @Nesse That's a different problem than what you describe in the question (or what the code implies at all), but they still can't have _both specifications_ on the same row.

Comment: I'm going to try out some of your examples and let you know if they work. Sometimes we have bundled products that we use as set, so multiple manufacturers are possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the product ids that you want if you group by product and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.Id
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN ProductManufacturer pm ON p.Id = pm.ProductId 
INNER JOIN ProductSpecificationAttribute psa ON p.Id = psa.ProductId
WHERE pm.ManufacturerId = 6 AND psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId IN (17, 1016)
GROUP BY p.Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId) = 2; -- both specifications must exist
```

If you want to count these products you could either use the above query as a subquery or a cte and count the rows:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT p.Id
  FROM Product p
  INNER JOIN ProductManufacturer pm ON p.Id = pm.ProductId 
  INNER JOIN ProductSpecificationAttribute psa ON p.Id = psa.ProductId
  WHERE pm.ManufacturerId = 6 AND psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId IN (17, 1016)
  GROUP BY p.Id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId) = 2; 
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte;
```

or, use `COUNT()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER ()
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN ProductManufacturer pm ON p.Id = pm.ProductId 
INNER JOIN ProductSpecificationAttribute psa ON p.Id = psa.ProductId
WHERE pm.ManufacturerId = 6 AND psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId IN (17, 1016)
GROUP BY p.Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT psa.SpecificationAttributeOptionId) = 2;
```